# Auto complete (Jquery) focus doesn't bind Spring Propety

Tags: spring, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am working on Auto complete (jquery) using Spring MVC. I have done everything, data is displaying properly in auto complete but properties doesn't display onfocus event. Whenever i call "ui.item.username" in onfocus method, it always display me null value.

```
$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "person.ajax",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                maxRows: 6,
                startsWith: request.term
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                response( $.map( data.zipcodes, function( item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.realName + item.realName,
                        value: item.username
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
```

it works fine till here but when i call property in onfocus methods (in following method), it displays me null
in focus event (jquery)

```
focus: function(event, ui) {
    alert($( event.target ).val(ui.item.ealName)); // it displays me null value at this point
},
select: function( event, ui ) {
}
```

Any Suggestion?

Comment: Are you saying that ui.item.ealName is a null value or that $(event.target).val(ui.item.ealName)) is a null value? val(value) is a setter in this context.  it should be returning a null in the alert.  Try to simplify your issue.  It sounds like the error is in the focus method.

Answer (score 1):

The result object you're building in the `success` function of your AJAX request is used across all methods/event handlers of the autocomplete widget. If you want to access a property later, you'll have to include that property when you're building the data source you're passing to the `response` function:

```
success: function( data ) {
    response( $.map( data.zipcodes, function( item) {
        return {
            label: item.realName + item.realName,
            value: item.username,
            realName: item.realName // include realName
        }
    }));
}
```

(From the comments):

Also the `alert` function *does* return `null`, so if you'd like to alert just the value, use:

```
alert(ui.item.realName)
```

instead.

Comment: success: function( data ) {
    response( $.map( data.zipcodes, function( item) {
     return {
      label: item.realName+ item.realName,
      value: item.username,
      realName: item.realName
     }
    }));
   }
   
   });
  },
      focus: function(event, ui) {
       alert( $( event.target ).val(ui.item.realName));
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
     }

Comment: success: function( data ) {
    response( $.map( data.zipcodes, function( item) {
     return {
      label: item.realName+ item.realName,
      value: item.username,
      realName: item.realName
     }
    }));
   }
   
   });
  },
      focus: function(event, ui) {
       alert( $( event.target ).val(ui.item.realName));
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
     }

Comment: `val` does not return anything when used that way. Try just `alert(ui.item.realName);`

Comment: jQuery changes so quickly that its tough to recommend a book, but I do know that the [jQuery tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) on jQuery's website are pretty good. I also recommend [The Definitive Guide](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Definitive-Guide-Activate-Guides/dp/0596805527/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1357323453&sr=8-1&keywords=The+definitive+guide+javascript) as an overall JavaScript book.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented auto complete drop down using spring mvc. Now my question is when any user select/choose any value from auto complete drop down, then How can i sure that the selected value is correct or not? in other words i want to ensure that whether user selected the correct value from auto complete or not. Because user can type random string in input text box and submit it(Technically, i also make sure when user select any value from drop down, then submit will be visible to the user, and if user type incorrect data, the button shouldn't be activate).

Here is a code

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "input[name='creditCheck']" ).autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source:function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "creditCheck.ajax",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        maxRows: 6,
                        startsWith: request.term
                    },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map( data.creditCheckData, function( item) {
                        return {
                            creditName: item.creditName,
                        }
                    }));
                }

                });
            },
```

The above code words fine, it get the list from server and displays the auto complete data.In following code i am just toggling the button.But i also make sure when user select any value from drop down, then submit will be visible to the user, and if user type incorrect data, the button shouldn't be activate.

```
$('input[name="creditCheck"]').bind("change keyup", function () {
    if ($(this).val()!="") {
        $(this).nextAll("button[name='add']:first").removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $(this).nextAll("button[name='add']:first").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```